# Specify how much time CSS or JS can be cached

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel-5, httpd.conf

Where and how do I have to put the time a browser can cached my CSS and JS.

Can anyone give me an example of the way I have to do to specify that a CSS can be stored for a year?.

Im using Ubuntu with Apache, and Laravel 5.2 (php)

Thank you

Comment: You need to add and expiration header to your server css response and that's it!

Comment: You'll need to specify what server your using. This is a server configuration, and has nothing to do with the contents of any given file, which makes the HTML and CSS tags completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .htaccess for this - add something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 year"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This assumes the user is in an environment where `.htaccess` files are appropriate.

Comment: But I want to do it in the header of the html

Comment: Granted. Since the OP didn't give any information about that, I assumed, since most webservers for mundane tasks run Apache. Granted, most of what can be done in .htaccess have equivalents in other languages, and can therefore be modifed to match.

@JoaquinColella why?